# Solar Battery Pack for outdoor lights

Tags: outdoor, solar

I recently bought a really old house and the light outside has not been working. I just found that there was a little solar battery charger laying on the floor of my front yard, broken to pieces. So I want to replace the solar battery pack with a new one so I can get my lights going again, but I have not found what I am looking for.

The current (and broken) battery pack is about 12" wide, 4" deep. It comes with 3 rechargeable AA Batteries in the back, an On/Off switch, and a bunch of wires coming out of it. The battery pack had a wire coming out of it that was attached to the lamp post itself.

I am absolutely ignorant to anything electrical, but I think I could manage wiring it all up if I can find the right item. The problem is, all I can find is trickle battery chargers for 12-volt batteries. I don't want that, I want something with rechargeable AA batteries in it. I would prefer something that can take 6 or 8 AA Batteries, as I would like for my lights to stay on through the night.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am looking for? I have searched for, and many variants of, the words "Solar Battery Charger Pack" but no luck. Would a 12-volt trickle down charger work for me? I did not think it would, since it does not hold any charge but just charges right then and there.

[image: solar pack - back]
[image: solar pack - front]

Comment: Are there any manufacturer markings on the remains of the battery pack? How about on the light itself? Your best bet would be to hit up the mfgr's web site to at least find the required specs then look for something that meets those specs (assuming their pricing is too high, otherwise, just buy an OEM replacement from them).

Comment: A photo and or part number would be helpful here there should be some markings on it.

Comment: @FreeMan There aren't any part numbers on the battery pack. The only clue I have is, the batteries have the brand "Yards & Beyond" on them. I tried looking that up and all I could find are the batteries, not the charger.

Comment: @EdBeal I will add some photos in a bit.

Comment: There are no manufacturer markings at all on the light itself? You may need to remove a cover to find a label on the inside.

Comment: @EdBeal Ive added images of the battery pack

Comment: @FreeMan The lamp itself is a standalone lamp on a lamp post. It seems like the solar power was an afterthought; as though it was originally intended to be a "regular" lamp (powered by a power cable going underground from inside the house). There is a cable the same size as in the images hanging from the lamp, disconnected from the solar pack. Likewise on the solar panel, a disconnected cable.

Comment: I had a weather station like those from Oregon scientific I will see what I can find. 3 double a size rechargeable batteries right?

Comment: @EdBeal Yes, the current one has 3 AA batteries. I am hoping I can find one similar, but one that would take more batteries so it can power more devices (or one device through the night). But the bare minimum, the same device is better than nothing! Thank you, I will await your response.

Comment: I did look and could not find a replacement for the model I had. There was a Himvsion that was only ~30$ but it did not have the battery back up the ones I found that had battery back up at 4.5-5 v were for cameras closer to the 70-80$ range , I think my Oregon scientific weather station had 3 solar cells with rechargeable battery back up much like yours, and that with all the sensors was only 250 10-15 years back but I cannot find that model or replacement parts sorry. It might be better to get a system like bunker hill security 120 lumen solar powered motion light for 18$ at harbor freight